# How can I use std::shared_ptr with the Mysql prepared statements?

Tags: c++, mysql, boost, prepared-statement, shared-ptr

How can I use `std::shared_ptr` with the Mysql prepared statements? is there any requirements which I should know in this case? is there any difference between `boost::shared_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any details about MSQL API functions that you actually use, so this answer is also generic.

If you should create and delete your pointer using the following API functions:

```
API_OBJ *api_obj_create( ... );
api_obj_delete(API_OBJ*);
```

To manage your pointer with `std::shared_ptr` you need to provide the custom deleter:

```
std::shared_ptr<API_OBJ> my_s_ptr(api_obj_create( ... ),
    [](API_OBJ* p) { api_obj_delete(p); });
```

Standard library is usually preferred over boost library.

Answer (score 1):

**header**

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

sql::Driver *host_1_driver; 
boost::shared_ptr <sql::Connection> host_1_conn;
boost::shared_ptr <sql::Statement> host_1_stmt;
boost::shared_ptr <sql::ResultSet> host_1_res;
boost::shared_ptr <sql::PreparedStatement> host_1_pstmt;        

bool reconnect_state = true;    
std::string host_1_name;
std::string host_1_user_name;
std::string host_1_password;
std::string host_1_database_name;
```

**connect**

```
host_1_driver = get_driver_instance (); // protected            
host_1_conn.reset(host_1_driver->connect (host_1_name, host_1_user_name, host_1_password)); // connect to mysql
host_1_conn->setClientOption("OPT_RECONNECT", &reconnect_state);    
host_1_conn->setSchema(host_1_database_name);
```

**thread**

```
void float_to_sql(std::string query, std::vector <float> data_to_write, std::vector <float> data_ids)
{
    host_1_driver->threadInit();    // prevents multiple open connections
    if (host_1_conn.get() == NULL)
    {
        ERROR << "host_1 connection is not open";
        throw -1;
    }       
    host_1_pstmt.reset (host_1_conn->prepareStatement (query));
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) data_to_write.size(); i++)
    {
        host_1_pstmt->setDouble(1, data_to_write.at(i));
        host_1_pstmt->setInt(2, data_ids.at(i));
        host_1_pstmt->executeUpdate();
    }               
    host_1_driver->threadEnd();                 
    return;
}
```

**test**

```
std::string query = "update ErrorCodes set Val = ? where ID = ?";
std::vector <float> data {1, 1, 1};
std::vector <float> data_ids {3, 5, 9};
float_to_sql(query, data, data_ids);
```